# Selecting a specific sheet based off either number from 0 or name

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, export-to-pdf

I am trying to generate an email with a PDF attachment of a specific sheet, not necessarily the active sheet. I have tried referencing the specific sheet name as well as the number, but to no avail, it chooses sheet 1, titled 'AMDashboard_English'. Please help.

```
function CreatePDF() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("AMDashboard_English");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("AMDashboard_English");
  Logger.log(sheet.getName());

  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SS_ID/export?".replace("SS_ID", sheet.getId());

  var url_ext = 'exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf'   // export as pdf / csv / xls / 

  var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets(); 

  var blobs = [];
  var i=0

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(
    url + url_ext + sheets[i].getSheetId(), {
      headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token}
    }
  );

  blobs[i] = response.getBlob().setName(sheets[i].getName() + '.pdf'); 
  DriveApp.createFile(blobs[i]);
  return blobs[i];
}
```

Comment: a workbook ID (`SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getId()`) and a sheet ID (aka grid ID, `SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("some name").getSheetId()`) are not the same thing. https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts#common_terms

Answer (score 0):

The url should be of the format below:

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/[SPREADSHEET_ID]/export?format=[PDF]&gid=[SHEET_ID]
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that the code actually does work as planned. The reason it was not working is that I had another set of code referencing the same var's which apparently confused google scripts. All is well. Thank you.